# How to call onClick function from anchor tag by click on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on the database value status will be `Y` or `N` . If it `Y` means it will `active.png` will be display. it is working fine. when i click `active.png` image then  anchor tag `id="activeStatus"` onclick function is not working.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#DomainID").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#example tbody tr").remove();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: '@Url.Action("ViewModules")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data.EmpList, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();

                            /*Find Role here - Comparing Emp List ModuleId to RoleList ModuleId*/

                            var RoleName = $(data.role).filter(function (index, item) {
                                return item.ModuleID == item.ModuleID
                            });

                            if (item.ParentModuleID == -1) {

                                item.ModuleName = " -- " + item.ModuleName
                            }
                            else {
                                item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName
                            }

                            var Status = '';
                            if (item.Status == "Y") {
                                Status = '<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="activeStatus" title="Disable status"><img src="/img/Active.png" height="22" width="42"/></a>'
                            } else {
                                Status = '<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="inActiveStatus" title="Active status"><img src="/img/InActive.png" height="22" width="42"/></a>'
                            }

                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.ModuleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.Url + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + RoleName[i].RoleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + '<a href="@Url.Action("EditModules", "Account")?id=' + item.ModuleID + '" class="font-icon font-icon-pencil" title="Edit"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + Status + "</td>"
                                + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Click Event:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#activeStatus').on('click', function () {
                alert("Status Clicked");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Event handling of the dynamically created element is different. You may check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.on` method but not for `dynamically` appended elements.

You have to use `event delegatio`n for elements which were added **dynamically**.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

You should `bind` click event handler using `.on()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example tbody').on('click', '#activeStatus', function () {
          alert("Status Clicked");
      });
});
```

Method has to be called with `3` parameters:

- the event
- the target element
- the **callback** function executed after event is triggered.

Comment: Just as a side note, binding click event to `document` makes your ready wrapper useless here :)

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes, in this situation it can be used `$(#example tbody).on()`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai [how-to-pass-id-value(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772344/how-to-pass-id-value-onclick-function-from-anchor-tag-by-click-on-image-using-mv)